# Solving latency between AVPlayer and NSSound

Tags: macos, audio, avfoundation, latency

I am getting a latency that seems dependent on the computer, between AVFoundation and the simple [NSSound play].
My program is playing one video track and 3 audio tracks arranged inside an AVPlayer. This is working nicely.  Independently, the program generates a metronome for each beat of the measure, following information from the music score.  The two metronome sounds are very short files that I load in an NSSound and use [NSSound play] to play them.  I noticed that I had to shift the metronome playback of about 90 milliseconds so that it is perfectly synchronized.  Part of it may be the exact moment when the impact of the metronome is located in the metronome file, but if that was the only reason, then this delay would be the same on all Mac computers.  However, on different Macs, this delay must be adjusted.  As it is a metronome beat synchronized with the music, it is quite critical, as a slight shift makes it sound off beat.  Is there any way to calculate this delay directly from AVFoundation API ?  Or to compensate it or to play the metronome in another way so that there is no delay between the AVPlayer and the NSSound play ?  I would appreciate some link or idea about this.
Thanks !
Dominique
Arpege Music, Belgium

Comment: You don't mention how you are scheduling the sounds. Sounds to me as though you might be using an NSTimer - which has all manner of issues.  If this question becomes one of how to reliably schedule your metronome sounds, it's one I've answered on here a few times before. Let me see if I can find the answers.

Comment: Thanks Marko.  To schedule the sound play I use indeed an NSTimer, but I set it up in a separate thread, with its own event loop, just for that. This way it is very stable, there are no glitch.  The only problem is to find how to calculate the delay that I must add or subtract to this metronome play, as it seems machine dependent.  This thread is watching the AVPlayer time value and when appropriate, it fires the sound play.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into a low level audio library to manage and instantly play your music. [BASS](http://un4seen.com) is a low level library built upon Audio Units which allows for refined, precise and fast control over your stream. By manipulating your buffer, and possibly creating a mixer stream (Refer to the docs) you should be able to instantly play the sound on any device. Specifically, look into buffering the sound before hand and keeping it in memory since it's a short sound.